# Laravel - Get column names when eager loading from the model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do you get column names when eager loading is specified in the model?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work. I can't seem to select any columns from the channel model.

```html
$query = Transaction::select('id', 'processing_time', 'uniqueId', 'paymentType', 'status', 'channel:uuid');

return $query->take(5)->get();
```

If I do this however, I get everything from transaction & channel so the relationship is there and working.

```html
$query = Transaction::limit(5);

return $query->get();
```

**Transaction model**

```html
protected $with = ['channel'];

public function channel() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Channel::class, 'entityId', 'uuid');
}
```

**Channel model**

```html
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'entityId', 'uuid');
}
```

Comment: Add entityId  column in your select statement, then it will retrieve the data for the channel relationship.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work mate

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs on eager-loading:

`When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns`

Try:

`$query = Transaction::select('id', etc.., 'channel:id,uuid');`

Or

`$query = Transaction::select('id', etc..)->with('channel:id,uuid');`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = Transaction::with(['channels' => function($query){
             $query->select('you', 'colums')
    });
```

You can use Select in your Relationship like this.

Comment: But if the "with" is specified in the model, does it need to be specified again in the controller to make this work? Seems kind of redundant.

Answer (score 0):

in channel model add select as

```
public function channel() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Channel::class, 'entityId', 'uuid')->select(array('columns name you want to get'));
}
```

Comment: And then how would I specify the column in my query? channel:uuid is still brining back unknown column.